# what are limit points of $X \times \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\{0,1,2 \}$ has order topolgy and $\mathbb{N}$ has natural order topolgy. Suppose $X \times \mathbb{N}$ has dictionary order topology then what are limit points of $X \times \mathbb{N}$ ?

**Answer:**

\begin{align*}X \times \mathbb{N} =& \{(0,1), (0,2), \cdots, (0,n), \cdots \\ & (1,1), (1,2), \cdots, (1,n), \cdots \\ & (2,1), (2,2), \cdots, (2,n), \cdots \}\end{align*}

Now let $<$ be the dictionary order, then $(x,y)<(a,b)$ if either $x<a $ or $x=a \ and \ y<b$.

Any open set in $X \times \mathbb{N}$ has the form $U=\left((a,b), (a',b') \right)$, where $(a,b) < (a',b')$.

If $(\alpha, \beta) \in U$, then $ (a,b)<(\alpha, \beta)<(a',b')$.

Then take the point $(0,3)$ and its nbd $U=((0,2),(0,4))$, clearly $(0,3) \in U$ but $U \cap ((X \times \mathbb{N}) \setminus \{(0,3)\})=\phi$.

Hence $(0,3)$ is not a limit point.

Similarly we can show that no point is limit point.

So the set $X \times \mathbb{N}$ has no limit point.

Am I right?

Comment: The letter `\phi` $\phi$ is not commonly used to denote an empty set. The appropriate symbol here is `\emptyset`  $\emptyset$, but due to its ugly look many prefer `\varnothing` $\varnothing$ instead.

Comment: All points $(n,1), n \ge 1$ are limit points; use the fact that open intervals form a local base. And a point left of $(n,1)$ has infinitely many $(n-1,k)$ points between  it and $(n,0)$ still.

Comment: Ah, $X$ is only finite so that leaves $(1,1)$ and $(2,1)$ as the unique limit points. All other points are isolated as $(0,1) = [(0,1), (0,2))$ (special treatment as the minimum), $\{(n,k)\} = \left((n,k-1),(n,k+1,)\right)$ if $k \ge 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument for $(0,3)$ works for $(m,n) \in X \times \mathbb N$ as long as $n \ge 2$, and a similar argument also works for $(0,1)$.

However, that argument does not work for $(1,1)$ or for $(2,1)$.

To see why, consider a basis element $U$ of the topology that contains $(1,1)$, and so $U$ has the form $((a,b),(a',b'))$ where $(a,b) < (1,1) < (a',b')$. Since $(a,b) < (1,1)$ it follows that $a=0$. Thus the entire sequence of the points $(0,b+1), (0,b+2), (0,b+3),...$ is in the set $U$, and $(1,1)$ is a limit of that sequence. Since this is true for all choices of $U$ it follows that $(1,1)$ is a limit point of $X \times \mathbb N$. By a slightly more complicated argument you should also be able to prove that $(2,1)$ is a limit point.

By the way, just to correct a minor error, the elements $U = ((a,b),(a',b'))$ form a basis for the topology on $X \times \mathbb N$ as I said, however it is not true to say that any open set has that form. In general an open set can be expressed as a *union* of some collection of basis elements, but that collection might have more than just one basis element.